# Is the new review system officially out of beta?

Tags: support, review

Is the new review system officially released as production, no longer considered beta?

Regarding questions about review, should the [review-beta](/questions/tagged/review-beta) tag no longer be used?

Comment: I'd imagine someone from SE will just synonymize the tags when the new review is officially out of beta.

Comment: I would have thought the `review-beta` tag would stay, so that people could differentiate between stuff asked during the different phases - IOW people can clearly see which version of the review a question relates to.

Comment: @slugster Well, when the new review becomes the only review, I'd imagine several of the then obsolete Meta posts about the old review will disappear gently into the night...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'll be putting up a blog post within the next couple of weeks "announcing" the feature more broadly. That will probably represent the official transition out of the current (public) beta mode.

That said, we will still be watching behavior and feedback here on meta and expect the feature to continue to evolve a lot after that "formal" launch.